# Why can I hear my SSD 'grinding' for disk operations - when it is solid-state?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

We all know SSDs are the latest-and-greatest in storage technology.

Massively faster then the older HDD, because there is no physical arm for a servo to move to read the correct data off the drive.
In fact, there is no physical movement at all: It's all Solid-state.

It's even in the name **S**olid **S**tate Drive.

So why when I open a new application, or shut down some process, do I hear the SSD 'grinding', like it used to in the good old HHD days?

I've got great hearing, but I'm pretty sure I can't hear electrons squeezing through narrow tracks, or transistors switching on and off...

**EDIT** There is definitely no HDD or hybrid drive in the machine.

It's very faint, like the sound when you pass throught the RF anti-theft devices in libraries and stores.

It definitely occurs on data access.

Comment: It's probably your second non-SSD drive in there, or your CD drive that you can hear. Also some hard drives are hybrid, which means they have both mechanical and solid state parts inside,

Comment: I have heard a a slight hum on some cheap Chinese SSDs.  Probably due to the low cost electronics.

Comment: @Keltari It is a factory Dell Inspiron 7591 - 6 months old. Perhaps it has some cheap chinese junk installed from factory....

Comment: @Ramhound The (factory) drive is an "NVMe IM2P33F3 NMVe AD"

Comment: A hum from a cheap capacitor is very different when saying it’s a grinding sound.  Understanding what SSD you have exactly would be very helpful.  It would also be helpful to know what other drives you have installed.  “very faint, like the sound when you pass throught the RF anti-theft devices” - That’s a bad capacitor, and it’s absolutely NOT your SSD, its probably just near it.

Comment: I would put the IM2P33F3 in another computer and make sure it is the NVMe device, because I like most other doubt that it is coming from there.  If for ANY reason you can prove this device is make the noise by eliminating ALL other possible causes replace it IMMEDIATELY.  NO other NVMe or SSD makes any kind of noise.  If can be proved it is this device I would like to know so I can blacklist it and make sure nobody I know buys one.,

Comment: Probably "coil whine".

Answer (score 14):

The noise comes form the SSD changing power states, which is happening a few thousand times per second, which causes a piezo electric effect (small movement due to electricity) in the drive, creating an audible noise. To resolve, you can turn off the C-state power option in the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

For additional info I am sharing a [Dell Knowledge Base Article](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-aw/000150362/the-solid-state-drive-ssd-on-my-laptop-makes-a-strange-squeal-buzzing-noise):

> Some portable systems equipped with solid state drives (SSD) emit an
> audible squeal when the system is idle or under light use.   This is
> normal behavior.
>
> In order to save energy when the Central Processing Unit (CPU) is
> idle, the CPU can be set to enter a lower-power mode, also known as a
> "C-State". The intent of lower power modes is to cut power use inside
> the CPU. In certain situations, a high-frequency buzzing noise can be
> heard from the system. This buzzing noise appears with a change in
> processor activity, SSD load, or if Universal Serial Bus (USB) devices
> are attached.
>
> The noise comes from the processor’s power circuit and can only be
> heard when the processor is in C3 (clock-stopped or sleep) power
> state. The noise is generated from the processor's power circuit,
> which is caused by a phenomenon referred to as the Piezoelectric
> Effect. When a specific voltage is applied to these solid state
> components, they begin to resonate producing sounds that fall within
> the range of human hearing (15 – 20 KHz).
>
> This is the noise that is heard from the system, and **is not indicative
> of a problem or failure.**
>
> If the system BIOS has a C-States option, disabling this option should
> help eliminate the noise.
>
> **NOTE**: This buzzing noise exists to some degree on all laptops but some
> users perceive this as abnormal because it is different from the other
> more familiar noises systems make.

Answer (score 1):

I've also heard this noise on SSD only computers.  Most computer towers have switching power supplies. Switching power supplies sometimes made audible sounds, especially when it's load is changing quickly. And if you listen closely, the sound is very similar to the typical hard drive "ticking" sound.

Answer (score 0):

SSDs don't have mechanical parts and don't make any noise at all.  The only possible reason an SSD would be making noise is:

- your system has some major electrical issues.
- the SSD is really an SSHD: these are mechanical hard drives with a bit of flash memory as cache - a hybrid.  These will make typical mechanical hard drive noises.
- you bought a cheap external USB or other drive from an unreputable buyer and there's really a mechanical hard drive in it.

If you are 100% sure the noise is coming from the SSD drive, and have checked the model to make sure it is a true SSD and not an SSHD hybrid or other, you should troubleshoot your computer hardware starting with the power supply and incoming power to the system.